# How can I ignore certain files in a repo so they wouldn't be shown in the `languages used` area?

Tags: github, github-api

After creating an exe file for a py file using the `py-to-exe` module my "`languages used`" area in my repo have changed to show that it contains 99% qml files.

[image]

At first I didn't really minded that because it didn't changed anything until I looked again on my whole account languages used and saw that

[image]

I know it's just cosmetic but it still doesn't look well and I need to remove it.
I also need the repo in question to stay public.

I tried searching online for a way to hide certain languages from github's tracking

I tried adding  a `gitattributes` file and in it threw this line to try and ignore this language:

```
*.qml linguist-detectable=false
```

[image]

I tried spelling `qml` with small and big letters, but it still wasn't ignoring it.

Is there something that I am missing?

**-----*-*-------**--